# CDF of $\max(X,X^2)$ for $X$ uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. And $Y=max(X,X^2)$.

What is $F_{Y}(t)$ , the CDF of $Y$?

**My attempt:**

I tried to graph it, but I think I found wrong. I found the joint pdf $5/6$. Is this correct? And what can I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $0\leqslant Y\leqslant1$ almost surely and that $[Y\leqslant y]=[-\sqrt{y}\leqslant X\leqslant y]$ for every $y$ in $(0,1)$. The length of the interval $[-\sqrt{y},y]$ is $y+\sqrt{y}$ hence $$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leqslant y)=\tfrac12(y+\sqrt{y}).$$

Comment: How can you understand that $[−y<X<sqrt(y)]$

Comment: I think your interval should be -sqrt(y) < X < y, since y^2 < y on (-1,1), but the final answer is correct.

Comment: Indeed: $Y\lt y$ means that $X\lt y$ and $X^2\lt y$, that is, $X\lt y$ and $-\sqrt{y}\lt X\lt\sqrt{y}$, and $\sqrt{y}\gt y$ hence this is $-\sqrt{y}\lt X\lt y$. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 5):

Using the joint cdf may not be the easiest way.

If $X\le 0$, then $Y=X^2$. If $X\gt 0$, then $Y=X$. 
Let us find the cdf of $Y$. The only interesting part is for $0\le y\le 1$.

With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we have $X\le 0$. Conditional on $X\le 0$, the distribution of $X$ is uniform on $[-1,0]$. Thus
$$\Pr(Y\le y|X\le 0)=\Pr(X^2\le y|X\le 0)=\Pr(-\sqrt{y}\le X\le 0|X\le 0)=\sqrt{y}.$$

With probability $\frac{1}{2}$ we have $X\gt 0$. Conditional on $X\gt 0$, the distribution of $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Thus 
$$\Pr(Y\le y|X\gt 0)=\Pr(X\le y|X\gt 0)=y.$$
 We conclude that
$$F_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{y})+\frac{1}{2}y$$
for $0\le y\le 1$.

Comment: I don't think that your solution is right. Because when we put $y=1$ the result is $1/2$. But it must be $1$ I think. @Andre Nicolas

Comment: @Someone: Thanks, got tangled up with $1-(1-\dots)$. Fixed.